# Why is the data in a varchar field exceeding the size limit?

Tags: postgresql, import, psql, pg-dump

I have an application that is copying data from one PostgreSQL database to another. For the most part, that application works exactly as expected. However, there is a `comments` column in one of the tables in the source database that's defined as `character varying(6000)` that appears to be storing more than 6000 characters because, when I try to reimport the data to the destination database, I am getting errors:

```
890816: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(6000)
```

Once it encounters the error, it seems that the rest of the import fails with the result being that the table in the destination database is completely empty. All of the other tables appear to be populated normally, which is very strange to me because of the fact that many of the tables are defined with foreign key constraints tied back to the (now empty) table. In fact, I went to one of the larger *related* tables and compared the number of rows in both databases and the counts match exactly.

The overall process is more complicated, but this is the gist of it. I went to the field in question on the specific record and simply copied the text out of my editor into a notepad and it *does* appear that the value is actually `6045` characters long. *This database was designed long before I got my hands on it, so there are lots of references to other objects in the database preventing me from just quickly changing the size to a larger number or the type to `text`.*

In my application, I use `pg_dump` to dump the source database:

```
pg_dump.exe -h <HOST> -U <USERNAME> -p <PORT> -E UTF8 -O -x -v -f "<PATH_TO_FILE>" <DB1NAME>
```

Then I use `psql` to bring the data into the destination database:

```
psql.exe -h <HOST> -U <USERNAME> -p <PORT> -d <DB2NAME> -f "<PATH_TO_FILE>"
```

At this point, I'm testing a some code to edit the dump file from the source before the reimport and have it increase the column size in the destination from 6000 to 7000 (*I know that's not an actual solution, but I just need to try to get the replicated data into the destination.*) I absolutely wouldn't be surprised to find out that I've done something stupid somewhere along the line but I know that, at least at one time, this same basic functionality worked without any other apparent issues. I wish I could pin down when this problem started because I often don't get feedback on these issues for a long time.

Can someone please help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

---

### UPDATE FROM COMMENTS:

The possibility of an encoding mismatch wasn't something I had considered, so I checked both "sides" of the process:

Based on the `-E UTF8` switch I'm using with the `pg_dump` command I'm executing, the encoding of the dump file should be UTF-8. I was able to open the dump file in Notepad++, and it appears to confirm that the file's encoding is, indeed UTF-8:

[image: Dump File Encoding According to Notepad++]

Then, I went to the command line to check the encoding in the destination database:

```
psql.exe -h <HOST> -U <USERNAME> -p <PORT> -l
```

The results indicate that the destination is also using UTF-8 (redacted):

```
    Name    |   Owner    | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |     Access privileges
------------+------------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------
 db1        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db2        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db3        | admin      | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db3        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            | =Tc/dbadmins           +
            |            |          |                            |                            |            |                 | dbadmins=CTc/dbadmins+
            |            |          |                            |                            |            |                 | exceluser=c/dbadmins
 db4        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db5        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db6        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db7        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db8        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db9        | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db10       | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db11       | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 postgres   | postgres   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 db12       | dbadmins   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            |
 template0  | postgres   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            | =c/postgres              +
            |            |          |                            |                            |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1  | postgres   | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |            | libc            | =c/postgres              +
            |            |          |                            |                            |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
(16 rows)
```

So, it would appear that there is no mismatch in the data's encoding. I was able to go ahead and put a quick "tweak" in my application code that expands the size of that column in the destination database to accommodate for this issue, but it still doesn't make a whole lot of sense. The suggestion that it might be caused by data corruption seems, so far, to be the most likely scenario.

---

### UPDATE #2

(*from comments*)

> When I copy the text directly from the field in my DB explorer ([JetBrains DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)) and paste it into [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), it shows **6,045** characters.
>
> If I copy the value from the cell via [PGAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/), it shows **6,045** characters (excluding the quotation marks it automatically added).
>
> If I copy straight from the dump file, it shows **6,045** characters with the trailing space.
>
> If I query the column with:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT length(comments) FROM tbl WHERE id = 557242
> ```
>
> it returns a value of **6,000** characters.
>
> I looked through the text in Notepad++ and don't see anything that looks like unicode characters.

Riffing on the idea of encoding still being the problem, I ran a few more tests:

In DataGrip, I ran a `SHOW client_encoding;`. It returns a value of `UTF8`.

On my development workstation, I opened up a command line and connected to the database using `psql.exe`. Here, as soon as I connect, I get the following message:

```
psql (15.3)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.
```

Since I don't often directly interact with the database from the command line, that's the first time I recall seeing that message, but it seems pretty relevant to my understanding. I looked up the "[Notes for Windows users](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#:%7E:text=Notes%20for%20Windows%20Users)":

> psql is built as a “console application”. Since the Windows console windows use a different encoding than the rest of the system, you must take special care when using 8-bit characters within psql. If psql detects a problematic console code page, it will warn you at startup. To change the console code page, two things are necessary:
>
> - Set the code page by entering `cmd.exe /c chcp 1252`. (1252 is a code page that is appropriate for German; replace it with your value.) If you are using Cygwin, you can put this command in `/etc/profile`.
> - Set the console font to `Lucida Console`, because the raster font does not work with the ANSI code page.

I went ahead and ran the same `SHOW client_encoding;` query and it returns `WIN1252`.

So, doing a little more research, I ran across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023029/2569697) from the StackOverflow question, **PostgreSQL: encoding problems on Windows when using psql command line utility**. I'll try adding the suggested lines (`SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8` and `chcp 65001`) to the application's batch commands to change the code page "on-the-fly" and see if it resolves the issue.

While I'm certainly no expert, I have a feeling I'm on the right track now. The odd thing about this whole issue is that this behavior seems to be relatively new, although I can't say exactly when it started. This is a daily automated routine that runs overnight and, since it hasn't been throwing out any actual "errors", I didn't realize it was happening until I tried to look at the data for something else.

---

### DIDN'T WORK

I added the two lines to both of my batch files - the one for executing `pg_dump`, as well as the one for executing `psql` - and tested again without my "increase the field size" band-aid, but the problem persists. The `pg_dump` batch file looks like this:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=<DBPASS>
SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8
chcp 65001
pg_dump.exe -h <HOST> -U <USERNAME> -p <PORT> -E UTF8 -O -x -v -f "<PATH_TO_FILE>" <DB1NAME>
```

And the `psql` batch file looks like this:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=<DBPASS>
SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8
chcp 65001
psql.exe -h <HOST> -U <USERNAME> -p <PORT> -d <DB2NAME> -f "<PATH_TO_FILE>"
```

I'm running out of ideas, but I'm going to go ahead and reverse the changes I just made and move on for now.

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue.  What encoding is being used by psql?

Comment: And what encoding is embedded in the dump file?  `fgrep client_encoding dump.sql`

Comment: The other option would be that the origin database has some corruption.  Maybe someone fiddled with the catalogs manually, lowering the maximum length (atttypmod) after the table was already populated with now-violating data.

Comment: Thank you, @jjanes I hadn't considered encoding as a possible issue, but I don't think that's the problem at this point. According to the `pg_dump` command above, the dump file should be in UTF-8 (*seems to be confirmed when I look at the file in Notepad++*). Looking at the results of `psql -l`, it shows that all of the databases are also using UTF-8. So, I guess we're left with the possibility of database corruption.

Comment: To verify corruption, you could do something on the origin server (or a binary clone of it) to force the value to be rewritten, like `update foobar set bigcol=bigcol||'' where id=2;`  If there is corruption of the type I am postulating, this should fail with 'value too long'

Comment: @jjanes - Interesting. I did as you suggested (`UPDATE tbl SET comments = comments || '' WHERE id = 557242`). I didn't get an error. I got `1 row affected in 183 ms`.

Comment: Hmm.  Now I'm back to encoding.  If you are on different OSes or different versions, maybe they have different opinions about how to encode things even if they spell the encoding name the same?  Could you create a scratch database on the same server as the origin server and running the same PostgreSQL version, and try to restore there as a test?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid this might confuse the issue a bit. It's a long story as to why, but this "replication" process is actually taking one of the **databases** and replicating it into a **schema** in another database in the same PGSQL server instance on the same host. I can tweak the dump file to have it create another database or even another schema in one of the other databases, but the OS and PGSQL versions shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Wow, this looks more and more like magic.  Nothing is different but something is different.  At this point I'd probably ask someone else to look carefully in the data you extracted, to so see if they spot anything weird in there.  Have you tried putting that data extracted into notepad back in to the database?  How many characters do you need to chop off of it before it will fit?

Comment: When I copy the text directly from the field in my DB explorer (JetBrains DataGrip) and paste it into Notepad++, it shows 6,045 characters. If I do a `SELECT length(comments) FROM tbl WHERE id = 557242`, it returns a value of 6,000. If I copy the value from the cell via PGAdmin4, the length now shows 6,047 characters (*although that seems to be because it adds quotation marks around the text*). I looked through the text in Notepad++ and don't see anything that looks like unicode characters. If I copy straight from the dump file, it shows 6,044 characters (nvm - there's a trailing space).

Comment: @jjanes - Please see my **UPDATE #2**. I *think* I might be on the right track now. My best guess is that the issue may have started around the time we did an OS upgrade, but I couldn't swear to it.